# iPhone "disabled" when trying to enter recovery mode

Tags: iphone, itunes, recovery

I forgot my iPhone's lock code. I don't believe I have an iCloud/Find my iPhone configured on there. I never synced with iTunes. I'm fine with deleting all the content on the device.

I tried following the directions on [Apple's website to enter recovery mode](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201263):

1. Tap Volume up button.
2. Tap Volume down button.
3. Press and hold the side button.
4. This shows me the "slide to power off" slider and a "cancel" button.
5. Continuing to hold it restarts the iPhone.
6. The Apple Logo appears.
7. I continue holding the side button because it states:

   > don't release the buttons when you see the Apple logo, wait until the connect to iTunes screen appears
8. After the phone is done rebooting, I see a screen that says:

   > iPhone is disabled. try again in 15 minutes.
9. It does not enter recovery mode.

**Note**: I did try entering the passcode several times a day before and it got disabled for 15 minutes at the longest setting. However, I waited over 12 hours before I tried again, so the 15 minutes should not be a problem. To be sure, I waited another 15 minutes and repeated the whole process to no avail.

I even tried holding all 3 buttons to perform a restart, but this just entered Diagnostics mode, didn't show up in iTunes, and had no option to enter recovery mode.

No matter what I do, I can't get iTunes to recognize the device to start the recovery process.

I tried on another computer to no avail.

Any ideas how to enter recovery mode or wipe a phone if you forgot its password and it went into "disabled" mode?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the way to resolve this is:

1. Tap volume up
2. Tap volume down
3. Hold side button
4. When the "slide to power off" screen appears, let go of the side button.
5. Slide to **power off the phone completely**.
6. Once the phone is shut off, make sure it's plugged into iTunes.
7. Hold the side button to power on and **continue holding it** until the recovery screen shows up.

Therefore, the key is to shut it down completely instead of using the restart method as Apple recommends.